# BI Publisher - How to get rows to repeat in a table w/ dynamic column on RTF template

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, xslt-grouping, bi-publisher

I have a table where I am pivoting the data in the last column by accounting date as `(ACCOUNTING_DATE)` and a debit from one of the subledger tables as `(UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR)`.

I found an old tutorial on how to make dynamic columns so this is what I followed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu11uJ03S9Y
I'm not very experienced with template customization so I'd appreciate some help understanding how to adjust the formatting.

This is the overall structure of my table with how it's currently formatted:

| Customer Name `<?horizontal-break-table:1?>` | Account Number | Legal Entity | Contract Number | Obligation Number | Item | Item Description | Plan Start Date | Plan End Date | Contract Liability Account | Contract Revenue Account | Original Balance | Revenue Recognized | Open Balance | Revenue Determination | `<?for-each-group@column:G_1;ACCOUNTING_DATE?><?ACCOUNTING_DATE?><?end for-each-group?>` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<?for-each-group@section:G_1;CONTRACT_NUMBER?><?variable@incontext:CON;CONTRACT_NUMBER?><?CUSTOMER_NAME?>` | `<?ACCOUNT_NUMBER?>` | `<?LEGAL_ENTITY?>` | `<?CONTRACT_NUMBER?>` | `<?OBLIGATION_NUMBER?>` | `<?ITEM?>` | `<?ITEM_DESCRIPTION?>` | `<?PLAN_START_DATE?>` | `<?PLAN_END_DATE?>` | `<?CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT?>` | `<?CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT?>` | `<?ORIGINAL_BALANCE?>` | `<?REVENUE_RECOGNIZED?>` | `<?OPEN_BALANCE?>` | `<?REVENUE_DETERMINATION?>` | `<?for-each-group@cell://G_1;ACCOUNTING_DATE?><?if:count(current-group()[CONTRACT_NUMBER=$CON])?><?sum(current-group()[CONTRACT_NUMBER=$CON]/UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR)?><?end if?><?end for-each-group?><?end for-each?>` |

At present, it returns one line. However, the XML output from my data model has more lines by Obligation_Number, so I am trying to get the remaining lines to display.

This is the current output:[image: output]

Here is a snippet of theXML data:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<!--Generated by Oracle Analytics Publisher -Dataengine, datamodel:_Data_Model_xdm -->
<DATA_DS>
    <P_STARTDATE>2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00</P_STARTDATE>
    <P_ENDDATE>2024-01-31T00:00:00.000+00:00</P_ENDDATE>
    <P_CONTRACT_NUMBER>69022</P_CONTRACT_NUMBER>
    <G_1>
        <CUSTOMER_NAME>Customer #1</CUSTOMER_NAME>
        <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>1000</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
        <LEGAL_ENTITY>Company ABC</LEGAL_ENTITY>
        <CONTRACT_NUMBER>69022</CONTRACT_NUMBER>
        <OBLIGATION_NUMBER>72043</OBLIGATION_NUMBER>
        <ITEM>2018</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>Widget 1</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
        <PLAN_START_DATE>12-01-23</PLAN_START_DATE>
        <PLAN_END_DATE>11-30-24</PLAN_END_DATE>
        <CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>2000.10.000.000000.202000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>
        <CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>2000.10.510.170000.403000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>
        <ORIGINAL_BALANCE>150</ORIGINAL_BALANCE>
        <REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>25</REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>
        <OPEN_BALANCE>125</OPEN_BALANCE>
        <UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>12.5</UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>
        <REVENUE_DETERMINATION>PIT</REVENUE_DETERMINATION>
        <ACCOUNTING_DATE>12-31-23</ACCOUNTING_DATE>
    </G_1>
    <G_1>
        <CUSTOMER_NAME>Customer #1</CUSTOMER_NAME>
        <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>1000</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
        <LEGAL_ENTITY>Company ABC</LEGAL_ENTITY>
        <CONTRACT_NUMBER>69022</CONTRACT_NUMBER>
        <OBLIGATION_NUMBER>72065</OBLIGATION_NUMBER>
        <ITEM>337</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>Widget 2</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
        <PLAN_START_DATE>12-01-23</PLAN_START_DATE>
        <PLAN_END_DATE>11-30-24</PLAN_END_DATE>
        <CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>2000.10.000.000000.202000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>
        <CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>2000.10.510.170000.403000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>
        <ORIGINAL_BALANCE>695</ORIGINAL_BALANCE>
        <REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>115.84</REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>
        <OPEN_BALANCE>579.16</OPEN_BALANCE>
        <UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>57.92</UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>
        <REVENUE_DETERMINATION>PIT</REVENUE_DETERMINATION>
        <ACCOUNTING_DATE>12-31-23</ACCOUNTING_DATE>
    </G_1>
    <G_1>
        <CUSTOMER_NAME>Customer #1</CUSTOMER_NAME>
        <ACCOUNT_NUMBER>1000</ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
        <LEGAL_ENTITY>Company ABC</LEGAL_ENTITY>
        <CONTRACT_NUMBER>69022</CONTRACT_NUMBER>
        <OBLIGATION_NUMBER>72075</OBLIGATION_NUMBER>
        <ITEM>1841</ITEM>
        <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>Widget 3</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
        <CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>4000.10.000.000000.202000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT>
        <CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>4000.10.900.417000.405000.0000.00000.00000</CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT>
        <ORIGINAL_BALANCE>100</ORIGINAL_BALANCE>
        <REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>100</REVENUE_RECOGNIZED>
        <OPEN_BALANCE>0</OPEN_BALANCE>
        <UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>100</UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR>
        <REVENUE_DETERMINATION>PIT</REVENUE_DETERMINATION>
        <ACCOUNTING_DATE>12-14-23</ACCOUNTING_DATE>
    </G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

I tried creating a for-each loop by Contract_Number group but different iterations of this produces errors to where it does not run/return values. I've never done anything advanced like this in a template so I'm unsure how to modify the table.

Column #1, First Row:

```
<?horizontal-break-table:1?>
```

Column #1, Second Row:

```
<?for-each-group@cell://G_1;CONTRACT_NUMBER?>
    <?variable@incontext:CON;CONTRACT_NUMBER?>
    <?CUSTOMER_NAME?>

    <?for-each@cell://current-group();OBLIGATION_NUMBER?>
        <?OBLIGATION_NUMBER?>
        <?ITEM?>
        <?ITEM_DESCRIPTION?>
        <?PLAN_START_DATE?>
        <?PLAN_END_DATE?>
        <?CONTRACT_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT?>
        <?CONTRACT_REVENUE_ACCOUNT?>
        <?ORIGINAL_BALANCE?>
        <?REVENUE_RECOGNIZED?>
        <?OPEN_BALANCE?>
        <?REVENUE_DETERMINATION?>
        <?ACCOUNTING_DATE?>
        <?sum(current-group()[OBLIGATION_NUMBER=current()/OBLIGATION_NUMBER]/UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR)?>
    <?end for-each@cell?>

<?end for-each-group@cell?>
```

Comment: Seems you are grouping by CONTRACT_NUMBER, and your example data shows they all have the same CONTRACT_NUMBER.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I am. Initially it made the most sense to me since there are multiple customers, contract numbers, and obligation numbers. I wasn't certain how best to group by. 

I changed it to group by Obligation Number, and I'm seeing the correct number of lines now which is great. This leads me to a follow-up question for you if you don't mind - but what also determines it to sort/group logically if I'm only sorting for Obligation #? Is it because of the way my XML data is grouped?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. You can review the BI Publisher Reports Designer Guide and check for-each-group section for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Word (BI Publisher) Table wizard or you can make your own table. Here is a small sample with your data and with calculated column as last.
[image]

... and the result
[image]

Comment: Hi d r, I did give the pivot table a try first before I made my own table but it was quite limited. I just played around with it and didn't realize the table wizard was actually fairly decent! So if I wanted a dynamic column at the end where it displays the `UNROUNDED_ACCOUNTED_DR` values by the `ACCOUNTING_DATE` , how would that be implemented? I had made a group-by for the accounting date in the header, but I don't understand how that affects other grouping. I'm very new to XSLT.

Comment: @LindsayA. Well, it depends on how many dates (columns) should be created and how your report should look like if there are like 20 dates. I would probably try to solve it in my sql to get fixed number of columns beforehand. It could be done with sql using PIVOT or conditional aggregations or MODEL clause. The too many dates for report issue remains, though.